# Angular2 App with Alpha Router works with lite-server but not from WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm, router

I have a Angular2 app using the latest aplha router. Index file has `<base href='/'>`. Everything works beautifully when I run it using the lite-server. But it gives errors when I try to run from WebStorm 2016.1.3.

In WebStorm, I click the browser button from the `index.html` page.
It opens a browser to:
`http://localhost:63342/appdirectory/index.html?_ijt=pqspmbshs9epjf5rtjmalnjkke`

And I get multiple 404 error s for all my `.css` files and `systemjs.config` files.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Safari, Chrome and Explorer all give the same results.

Before I updated the router from the original v2, I had been able to run the app successfully from WebStorm. I never used the now deprecated beta component router.

Is there a configuration or work around for WebStorm and the latest router?
If not, am I better going back to the deprecated v2 router (and if so, can anyone point me to the documentation, I think its disappeared) or is the hash-style a better alternative?

I've looked at the github issues for Angular and the WebStorm issues page but haven't been able to find anything related to this.

Comment: Please can you check if the problem persist in 2016.2 EAP (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP), with "Allow unsigned requests" option enabled (Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just downloaded the EAP release and set the debug setting to "Allow unsigned requests". I received the same error.

Comment: I see, must indeed be caused by routing. Please feel free to vote for a feature request for HTML5 routing support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15762.
For now, using the server that supports HTML5mode to serve your files seems to be the only solution